# Running Backend And FrontEnd through Intellij Plugin

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webview, chromium-embedded, intellij-plugin

We are creating an IntelliJ plugin which  uses JCEF web-view to show the UI by reusing the components from our earlier command line tool. Earlier we had created a command line tool where we had our frontend in react and backend in spring boot.

In order to create the plugin we need a way to start both the backend (spring boot) and frontend (React) servers from the plugin itself. Basically when the user clicks the plugin's icon in Intellij it should start both backend and frontend servers. Can anyone please suggest a way/resources to achieve this?